# InputStream vs InputStreamReader

Tags: java, io

What's the benefit of using `InputStream` over `InputStreamReader`, or vice versa.

Here is an example of `InputStream` in action:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("c:\\data\\input-text.txt");

int data = input.read();
while(data != -1) {
  //do something with data...
  doSomethingWithData(data);

  data = input.read();
}
input.close();
```

And here is an example of using InputStreamReader (obviously with the help of InputStream):

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\data\\input.txt");
Reader      reader      = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

int data = reader.read();
while(data != -1){
    char theChar = (char) data;
    data = reader.read();
}

reader.close();
```

Does the Reader process the data in a special way?

Just trying to get my head around the whole `i/o` streaming data aspect in Java.

Comment: Note it's generally a good idea to specify a character set encoding when constructing an `InputStreamReader`. If you leave it out, then it will pick up whatever encoding happens to be configured in the right way (if that's what you want, then write it explicitly).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

They represent somewhat different things.

The `InputStream` is the ancestor class of all possible *streams* of bytes, it is not useful by itself but all the subclasses (like the `FileInputStream` that you are using) are great to deal with binary data.

On the other hand, the `InputStreamReader` (and its father `Reader`) are used specifically to deal with characters (so strings) so they handle charset encodings (utf8, iso-8859-1, and so on) gracefully.

The simple answer is: if you need binary data you can use an `InputStream` (also a specific one like a `DataInputStream`), if you need to work with text use an `InputStreamReader`..

Answer (score 34):

Well `InputStreamReader` is used to directly read characters.

So reading them as int and then converting to char is not really optimal.

That is the main difference I believe.

`InputStream` gives you the bytes, and the `InputStreamReader` gives you already chars so it reads the `InputStream` 8bits at a time.

In addition, if you're reading big chunks of text, you can even wrap the `InputStreamReader` in a `BufferedReader` which provides you with some nice methods to let's say read whole lines at once.

This helping you out ?

You can also read this article: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html

Cheers,

Comment: Yea, it makes sense.

Is there a way to specify a buffer, so that it reads more than 1byte at a time - say for instance I wanted it to read 1024 bytes at a time.

Comment: Hi,

Well if you use BufferedReader you can define the size of the Buffer as per the Javadoc "BufferedReader(Reader in, int sz)". However, for an InputStreamReader I believe this only ready 1 byte at a time. You can't change that.

Answer (score 12):

From InputStreamReader javadoc:

> A class for turning a byte stream into
>   a character stream. Data read from the
>   source input stream is converted into
>   characters by either a default or a
>   provided character converter. The
>   default encoding is taken from the
>   "file.encoding" system property.
>   {@code InputStreamReader} contains a
>   buffer of bytes read from the source
>   stream and converts these into
>   characters as needed.

For InputStreams, that actually contain characters in a known encoding, use the reader. Otherwise you just get the bytes and will have to do the conversion to char 'by hand'.

The difference between the two `read` methods:

`InputStream::read` reads a single `byte` and returns it as an `int` while `InputStreamReader::read` reads a single `char` (respecting the encoding) and returns this as an `int`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to read binary data use InputStream.

If you want to read strings from a binary stream, use InputStreamReader.  One of its constructors allows you to specify a character set.

For this reason do not use FileReader as it uses a platform default for a character set, which is, in many cases, not practical.

Answer (score 2):

**InputStream** helps us read byte streams
*whereas* **InputStreamReader** helps decode those byte streams into char streams using some charsets like UTF-8 or others.
*But* for more efficiency Java API recommends to use **BufferedReader** also along with **InputStream** and **InputStreamReader**

Answer (score 1):

InputstreamReader is used to read the Unicode's data which you can't read in inputstream.