# OutputStreamWriter vs FileWriter

Tags: java

I don't understand the difference between these two classes. When would you use one over the one? I know that FileWriter can output characters to a file but so can OutputStreamWriter as far as i know. Here is some code that i tested and they seem to work the same, i'm not adding the exception handling stuff but lets just assume its there.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\owner\\Desktop\\demo.txt");
writer.write("hello");
writer.close();
```

I also tried this code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\owner\\Desktop\\demo.txt");
os = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
os.write("hello");
os.close();
```

Both of these seem to work the same for me. The only time something strange happens is when i try to put an int value in the write() method. For the FileWriter example, my demo.txt is completely empty. For the OutputStreamWriter example i get some weird symbols in my text file. I am reading a java book and the only explanation i get for OutputStreamWriter is that it "converts a stream of characters to a stream of bytes" so shouldn't i be seeing some bytes in my text file in the second example?

Some clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A FileWriter is just short-hand for an OutputStreamWriter wrapping a FileOutputStream. Your two code examples are equivalent.

Comment: So is there ever a scenario when we would want to use an OutputStreamWriter over a FileWriter?

Comment: Yeah, when we don't want to write to a `FileOutputStream` but to another `OutputStream` :P Normally you would prefer a `OutputStream` as parameter to a method over a `FileOutputStream` as `FileOutputStream` is too specific.

Comment: ah ok that makes sense owlstead. Is it recommended to always use FileWriter then (i know about BufferedWriter, but just between the two in our discussion)?

Comment: Actually, you almost never want to use FileWriter, because there is no way to specify the encoding, which you almost always want to do. So you have to use OutputStreamWriter anyway. And maybe throw in a BufferedWriter, too.

Answer (score 52):

XXXInputStream and XXXOutputStream (where XXX varies, there's a lot of options) deal with 8-bit bytes.  For example, `OutputStream.write(byte[] c);`

XXXWriter or XXXReader deal with 16-bit chars.  For example, `Reader.read(char[] cbuf)`.

OutputStreamWriter converts an OutputStream to a Writer.  As you may have guessed, InputStreamReader converts from an InputStream to a Reader.  I am unaware of any classes that do the reverse, i.e. convert a Reader to an InputStream.

FileWriter is a Writer that talks to files.  Since a Java String internally uses chars (16 bit so they can handle Unicode), FileWriter is the natural class for use with Unicode Strings.

FileOutputStream is an OutputStream for writing bytes to a file.  OutputStreams do not accept chars (or Strings).  By wrapping it in an OutputStreamWriter you now have a Writer, which does accept Strings.

Now, the real question, is when do you use a Reader/Writer and when a Stream?  I've used Java for years and sometimes I get confused too.  I believe the following to be correct:

**Handy Guide - How to Decide Which to use:**

1. If you are dealing with binary data (e.g. an image) use Streams.
2. If you are using non-ASCII Unicode characters, e.g. Chinese, use
   Readers/Writers.
3. If you are using ordinary ASCII text (the traditional 0-127 characters) you can (usually) use either.

Some other links:

[inputstream and reader in Java IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764065/inputstream-and-reader-in-java-io)

[InputStream vs InputStreamReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194918/inputstream-vs-inputstreamreader)

Comment: This is the best answer.  The three points at the end is key.  I was writing Excel workbook streams downloaded from an HTTP connection and learnt about Stream vs Writer the hard way.  Simple rule: Use Streams for binary data (not normally human-readable) and Writer for text (human-readable info).

Comment: There aren't any classes to convert Reader->OutputStream or Writer->InputStream because you will never need to go from the high level wrappers (Readers and Writers) with higher abstraction and functionality, to low level streams (InputStream and OutputStream) with lower abstraction and functionality. You will only ever need to wrap the lower level Input/Output Streams with Readers/Writers to give them higher abstraction and functionality (e.g.: writing/reading character streams instead of byte streams)

Comment: But when I use      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:/temp/abc.txt");
        fos.write("hello".getBytes("你好"));  to write a chinese to text file, the file content is ok.

Answer (score 14):

There is actually no difference per se, `FileWriter` is just a convenience class. It extends `OutputStreamWriter` and creates the needed `FileOutputStream` itself.

Regarding `write(int)`: that method writes a single character with the specified codepoint to the stream, it does **not** write a textual representation of the numeric value.

As for the empty file, note that you should always flush the buffer when you want the things you've written flushed to the underlying store (be it a file or a network stream or whatever you can think of). Simply call `os.flush()` after writing, that should do it.
EDIT: As Thilo has correctly mentioned, closing the stream should already flush it (and all underlying streams).

And last but not least, you should nearly always explicitly specify the charset/encoding you want your Writer to write in. Writers write characters, while OutputStreams write bytes, so you have to specify how those characters should be encoded into bytes. If you don't specify an encoding, the system default gets used, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @Thilo: thanks for confirming that, I thought so myself, but I couldn't explain the different behavior. I just re-checked the source code of FileWriter, and it does absolutely nothing except passing the newly created FileOutputStream to the relevant super constructor. So I'm not really sure what could cause this discrepancy.

Comment: I made a mistake when i was typing the code into my IDE, instead of doing writer.close(); i left os.close(); and thats why my text file was empty.

Comment: @Thilo close() closes the underlying file output stream but it doesn't seems to be performing any explicit flushing of file output stream, at least, at the non-native code level. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @sactiw: Closing an OutputStream also flushes it.

Answer (score 3):

This is from [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t753243-diff-between-filewriter-f-txt-and-outputstreamwriter-new-fileoutputstream-f-txt.html)

> In java.io you either do byte IO or character IO. Byte IO can be used
>   for any form of data without any interpretation of what that data
>   represents. Character IO is meant for, well, information that is
>   represented as sequences of characters.
>
> For byte IO we have various types of InputStream/OutputStream classes
>   like the FileOutputStream from your example 1). For character data whe
>   have various forms of Reader/Writer classes like the FileWriter from
>   your example. Buffering can be done in both cases, hence the
>   BufferedWriter and BufferedOutputStream classes.
>
> To do character IO characters will at some point have to be converted
>   to byte data using some form of encoding. FileWriter does that for
>   you, which is why it has a constructor that takes the encoding along
>   with the file name. Common encodings include UTF-8, UTF-16 and
>   US-ASCII.
>
> OutputStreamWriter is a class that only does the encoding of
>   characters. That is why it is a Writer and its constructor takes an
>   OutputStream as parameter with an optional encoding parameter.
>
> If you omit the explicit encoding specifications both FileWriter and
>   ByteArrayOutputStream will use the default encoding for your platform.
>   This is something to be very careful with since it will vary among
>   different JVMs.

Comment: If OutputStreamWriter only does the encoding of characters, are you saying that FileWriter does the encoding of other types like int? Also this is probably dumb, but why do at some point characters have to be converted to byte data if what i wanted to do is just print them to the file?

Comment: @i'mhungry To make it simple, everything thing is a character from the perspective of doing a character IO but when it comes to writing it on disk (file) every character is represented in binary and it may take few bits (ASCII) to few bytes (UNICODE) depending on your choice of character encoding to represent it and thus this byte conversion (encoding) is required. To understand it better have a look at this [link](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Data/ascii.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the encoding, use OutputStreamWriter instead of a FileOutputStream.
FileOutputStream is a **convinient** class for writing character files. It uses default encoding.

Force encoding to UTF-8 as the following:

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream(exportPath),
    Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder() 
);
```

Comment: I came here because I wanted to know how to force encoding. I have tried both the above and simply declaring "UTF-8" (no forName or newEncoder), but the file created is always ANSI. Why is that? How do you truly FORCE the file to be created with the set encoding? And if "append" is set to true, will an existing file be converted to new encoding?

Comment: How can you tell a file's encoding without characters in them? Does it have BOM http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark ? I think you need to enforce the Byte Order Mark in your case. UTF-8 has an optional BOM character so an empty file is the same as an empty ANSI file. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html for the encodings.

Comment: The created file was not empty. There were stuff written and flushed into it after it was created.

Comment: Okay. So again. If the file does not have a unicode Byte Order Mark  you have to guess the file encoding for your own. Check this answer here : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file