# File charset changes to binary in docker container

Tags: java, docker

I have an application which listens to the external feed on hourly basis and receives the feed JSON which is a chunked transfer encoding stream, the listener to the feed write the chunk to the file, after the whole stream is completed another thread parses the file and extracts the data. But now while writing the file the data is written in binary format even though I have  specified the charset while writing.

```
    public void writeToFile(InputStream in){
     File feedFile = new File("/tmp/feed.json");
    try {
        FileUtils.touch(feedFile);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(in, writer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        FileUtils.write(feedFile, writer.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8,true);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error(Constants.FAILED_TO_WRITE_FEED_INTO_FILE,e);
    }
}
```

This code works fine on windows and linux box, but while inside docker container its written in binary format.

Docker container used Centos7

Comment: What do you mean with ```binary format```? Are the umlauts and other non-ascii stuff just scrambled?

Comment: See if @PaulRey answer helps. If not then try using `ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8` in your `Dockerfile` and see if it changes anything

Comment: @bratkartoffel here is what i mean `[root@f9d5003f866d tmp]# file -i feed.json
feed.json: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

you can see the charset is binary

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have printed the Current Encoding 
`{
  "Default Charset: ": "UTF-8",
  "Default Encoding:": "UTF8",
  "Default Locale:  ": "en_US",
  "file.encoding;   ": "UTF-8",
  "sun.jnu.encoding:": "UTF-8"
}`

Comment: @BrajeshPant have you actually looked in it?

Comment: Please don't trust file command inside docker. Copy the file outside the container and then check

Comment: @bratkartoffel i have tried the ways suggested here , also researched the net for UTF-8 encoding issue but i am not sure why the string encoding is getting changed

Comment: @TarunLalwani i Just copied , its still showing the same 
`file -i feed.json
feed.json: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

Comment: @BrajeshPant: I think you haven't understood what I wanted. Did you try to ```cat``` the file or open it in an hex-editor? What's actually wrong within the file?

Comment: @bratkartoffel `�i��+X���;�e")�\q:^m    L0/�4�n���6�B�v�A�~���m�M���1/N�.ET���T ig8Gc�P���B��I�H�{��6��ӘN+�K_��ɂ�Z�H�Lc�';܃�v��3Q:�%i�ix�c�hR8�zl6����H�A(8<��Z�2P��Q&��j
12I���e��\���Ci@bnO�����#�>�ϫ��棧�Y�25 2<��v
�`�͈�8kd�g�1�y����ͨ֊,C���iv:.�~�yk8��"�5E>;��5y�Qפ�����98��@zS�)���Q�▒��܀GRA�]�Y�;�WU�Ԁ��P���⃼h<�4,�y:�o��        ��'����` this is what i get in file after i do cat, this creates an issue while parsing this file via programatically

Comment: Have you also tried to debug the application? I think that the problem is, that the data coming from the InputStream is already broken. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46662125/remote-debugging-java-9-in-a-docker-container-from-intellij-idea

Comment: please provide a minimal repo to debug and reproduce this issue

Comment: I suspect that you're retrieving a compressed feed.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the locale UTF-8 in the container doesn't exist?

You can see the current locale in your running container with `cat /etc/locale.conf`

If it's not `LANG=en_US.utf8`, you can follow the instruction from [this StackOverflow post by user2915097](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406007/3756843):

> ```
> # Set the locale
> RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
>     locale-gen
> ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8  
> ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en  
> ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
> ```
>
> **Source:** How to set the locale inside a Ubuntu Docker container? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28406007/3756843

**EDIT 1:**

You should use `InputStreamReader` instead of `InputStream` because:

- `InputStream` is made to handle binary data
- `InputStreamReader` is made to handle text

You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3194956/3756843).

Comment: `[root@f9d5003f866d tmp]# cat /etc/locale.conf
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`


it exist, Also i am using Centos7

Comment: I know I linked a post about charset on Ubuntu but it works the same. I edited my answer to provide another approach.

Comment: I did use the InputStreamReader but no luck

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your dockerfile

```
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
```

It follows the same idea of the other comments you got, but uses dockers own mechanism.